# memory release with alloc

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

```
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate:[[NSDate alloc] init]];
```

when i use `[components release];`

it crashes my application, how do i release components

when i run with leak instrument - my application crashes when it reaches usage of overall alloc 22MB

Answer (score 3):

You must not release `components` yourself at all as it's set to autorelease by the `NSCalendar` object.

I suspect your leak is coming from your `NSDate` object that you pass to that line of code. You should probably assign that to a local variable, pass it to the `[cal components]` method then release the local variable:

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                      fromDate:today];
[today release];
```

Or, <del>set the `NSDate` object itself to autorelease as you pass it as you are doing,</del> use `[NSDate date]`, which as David Gelhar commented will generate an autoreleased object, like so:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                      fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: Quite right; the `[NSDate alloc]` causes a leak. Note that instead of using a temp and releasing it, you can also just use `[NSDate date]` to get an autoreleased `NSDate` object.

Answer (score 2):

The NSCalendar method `components:fromDate:` returns an autoreleased object; you must not call `release` on it yourself (unless you have first called `retain`).

Check out the [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)